# How to multi track export audio from After Effects to Audition

Tags: after-effects, audio, audition

I have a fairly complex AE project with multiple audio files playing at different times.  I'd like to make the final audio edit using Audition.

What's the best way to get all of my audio tracks from AE into a multi-track session in Audition?

I tried exporting as Premiere Pro project, and opening as a Premiere project in Audition, but that just made a bounced-down version in Audition.

Do I have to export each audio track individually from AE using the "Edit Menu-->Edit in Adobe Audition"?  Is there a script somewhere to do this quickly?

Comment: Seen [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/audition-effects-users.html)?

Comment: Hi, yes.  He's manually placing each audio file into the timeline in Audition.  I already have them in the right places in my AE timeline - is there an automated way of getting them into Audition at the right timings? Thanks!

Comment: Noticed that. False advertising. Sorry. Open the prproj in premiere and do it from [there](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/atv/cs5-cs55-video-tutorials/experience-an-integrated-audioforvideo-workflow.html).